# json_decode() php and how to reach variables in the array generated

Tags: php, arrays, json, variables

I am decoding a json record in php, here is the structure :

```
{relations":[], "entity":
 {"ide":1045, "status":"normal"}
}
```

Then my php code is :
    $result = json_decode($json, true);

How to reach "ide" and "status" values from the array $result ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: really? http://us.php.net/json_decode stack overflow is not a search engine. Finding this documentation entry literaly took me 2 seconds while just googlin json_decode.

Comment: Thank you but I read the doc and it was unclear to me how the associative array is set up. Sorry

Answer (score 3):

Since you specified in `json_decode` that you want to have an associative array you can echo your data like this:

```
echo $result['entity']['ide'];
echo $result['entity']['status'];
```

Comment: @AdamHopkinson: Thx. I don't know what is happening. The votes are changing every second from positive to negative and backwards again ... :D

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. Weird, I guess there's a couple of downvoters changing their minds at the same time!

Comment: Thanks for the help, appreciate...
Very clear answer for me, and it works :)

Comment: Glad it helped. Consider marking @AdamHopkinsons answer or mine as correct.

Answer (score 2):

With the second value set to true, your variables are in an array and so:

```
$result['entity']['ide'];
$result['entity']['status'];
```

If you miss out the true argument, your values would be in an object:

```
$result->entity->ide;
$result->entity->status;
```